# How to combine these two SELECT statment into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SELECT query which are written in `MySQL`

```
$sql = 'SELECT Name FROM category WHERE CategoryID = '.$id;
```

AND

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE ParentID = $id ORDER BY OrderIndex";
```

So far I have to translate these two query to `Oracle PL/SQL`‚I came in idea to combine these two statment into one and so far I write query but I am a little bit confusing since I am begginer in `PL/SQL`

```
SELECT 
  c.Name,
  sc.Name as SubCategoryName,
  sc.ID as SubCategoryID,
  sc.Picture as Picture,
  sc.OrderIndex
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN sub_category sc ON ParentID =
WHERE CategoryID = 23;
```

Here is graphical representation of tables

**CategoryTable**

[image]

**SubcategoryTable**

[image]

Comment: Try `SELECT c.name, sc.name subcategoryname, sc.id subcategoryid, sc.picture picture, sc.orderindex FROM category c JOIN sub_category sc ON sc.parentid = c.categoryid WHERE c.categoryid = 23;`

Comment: Combine how? Show us some sample result for each query, and also the combined result. All as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, joining tables is one of the standard ways to "combine two select statements together".
You are going to get different results depending on the kind of `join` you use.
See for instance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) for an explanation of the different kind of joins.

Your query is almost correct (assuming you want an `inner join`), you are missing the right hand side on the `join` condition:

```
SELECT 
  c.Name,
  sc.Name as SubCategoryName,
  sc.ID as SubCategoryID,
  sc.Picture as Picture,
  sc.OrderIndex
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN sub_category sc ON sc.ParentID = c.CategoryID
WHERE CategoryID = 23;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select is close to be working, you forgot to connect joined tables on their column which will result in error and there is no need to use `inner` as `inner join` = `join`. More useful information on joins can be found here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

This should work for you:

```
SELECT c.name,
       sc.name       subcategoryname,
       sc.id         subcategoryid,
       sc.picture    picture,
       sc.orderindex
  FROM category c
  JOIN sub_category sc
    ON sc.parentid = c.categoryid
 WHERE c.categoryid = 23;
```